# Taps server:: SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, taps

After heroku db:pull have been removed from the gem, I am trying to use taps.

```
 taps server mysql2://root@localhost/trappor2 taps taps123

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:
62:in `initialize': SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file (Se
quel::DatabaseConnectionError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapte
rs/sqlite.rb:62:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapte
rs/sqlite.rb:62:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/databa
se/misc.rb:45:in `block in initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/connec
tion_pool.rb:92:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/connec
tion_pool.rb:92:in `make_new'
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulty with taps recently too.  Try switching to PG backups if you can -- it's very straightforward:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export